# Makefile query-C

Tags: c, makefile

This was on an exam of mine and I'm reviewing and can't figure out why I lost points on it. Too late to ask the professor now so I'm here. Have I just not understood the basics of makefile? This is the problem:

> The file `engine.c` includes the file `engine.h` and `engine.h` includes the file `temp.h`. Write one or more makefile rules that generates the file `engine.o`."

This was my answer:

```
engine.o: engine.c engine.h
    gcc -c engine.c
```

The answer key says it should be:

```
engine.o: engine.c engine.h temp.h
    gcc -c engine.c
```

But I don't get it. The object file for `engine.c` doesn't depend on `temp.h` does it? `engine.h` depends on it. And I would handle `temp.h` if I was writing another target for `engine.h` but I'm not. Strictly speaking about the target for `engine.o`, do I need `temp.h`?

Comment: Does engine.h need to be re-built if temp.h changes? Or does engine.o need to be re-built if temp.h changes?

Comment: engine.h right? And ultimately engine.o I guess

Comment: When you update temp.h what do you have to do to engine.h? And what do you have to do to engine.o? (Keep in mind that Make cares about the *outputs* of each command - you compile engine.c, but from Make's point of view that's "doing something to engine.o")

Comment: The answer key is correct.  When `temp.h` changes, you need to rebuild `engine.o` — so you tell Make that `engine.o` is out of date unless it is newer than `temp.h` (as well as `engine.c` and `engine.h`).  In fact, you could omit `engine.c` from the list; Make will infer that dependency.

Comment: "engine.h right?". No, not right because header files do not need to be rebuilt (in general). If `temp.h` changes, nothing needs to be done to `engine.h`. The output which needs to be rebuilt is `engine.o`. Hence why the second answer is correct and not the first.

Comment: So if temp.h included another header file, I'd have to add that to the target as well?

Comment: Yes. But hopefully, today's compilers can do that for you, e.g. `gcc -M`

Comment: in general, a makefile needs to be written so it generates 'dependency' files, then the rule can be: `%.o:%.c %.d` followed by the 'recipe'.   The dependency files (one for each *.c file) contains ALL the header files,  Then if any referenced header file changes, then the *.o file will be re-created.  There are several ways to generate the dependency files.  If using `gcc`, there are parameters available to generate the dependencies.  The dependency files are included in the makefile via a statement similar to: `-include $(DEP)`  where `DEP` is a macro that contains list of dependencies files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To review:

> The file `engine.c` includes the file `engine.h` and `engine.h` includes the file `temp.h`

So that's:

*engine.c*

```
#include "engine.h"
```

*engine.h*

```
#include "temp.h"
```

*temp.h*

```
/* nothing */
```

If you modify `temp.h`, then **you need to rebuild `engine.o` from its parts,** because one of its parts is (eventually) `temp.h`.

When all the including is done, the code effectively looks like this:

> engine.c
>
> /* #include "engine.h" */
>
> > engine.h
> >
> > /* #include "temp.h" */
> >
> > > temp.h
> > >
> > > /* end of temp.h */
> >
> > ...
> >
> > /* end of engine.h */
>
> ...
>
> /* end of engine.c */

In fact, if you use something like `gcc -E engine.c > engine.i` you can see this for yourself. The `-E` option stops after the preprocessing phase, translating C source into C source-without-preprocessor-directives.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the contents of `temp.h` are:

```
#pragma once

void temp_function(int x);
```

and the contents of `engine.h` are:

```
#pragma once
#include "temp.h"

void engine_function(int a, int b);
```

and the contents of `engine.c` are:

```
#include "engine.h"

void engine_function(int a, int b)
{
   temp_function(a+b);
}
```

Let's also say that for some reason the contents of `temp.h` are changed to:

```
#pragma once

void temp_function(int x, int y);
```

Let's assume that `temp_function` is implemented in another file.

If you don't re-compile `eninge.c`, then the object code in `engine.o` for `temp_function` does not match the object code for the function in the file in which it is implemented. As a result, you will see a link time error. If you re-compile `engine.c`, you will see a compile time error.

It is always better to catch errors at compile time than at link time.

The rule

```
engine.o: engine.c engine.h temp.h
```

makes sure that the command to build `engine.o` is executed when `temp.h` is changed, and the compile time error is caught.

Answer (score 1):

engine.c depends on engine.h, and any change in engine.h can have significant change in engine.c

Similarly engine.h depends on temp.h, and any change in temp.h can have significant change in engine.h, which will indirectly have impact on engine.c

lets see this with an example:

in temp.h

```
#define ID 1
```

in engine.h

```
#define ENGINE_ID ID
```

in engine.c

```
engineId = ENGINE_ID;
```

if you modify ID, but in makefile rule is this:

```
engine.o: engine.c engine.h
gcc -c engine.c
```

the file will not recompile. But with

```
engine.o: engine.c engine.h temp.h
gcc -c engine.c
```

The file will get recompiled with new ID.

Comment: A change in `temp.h` may also change the results of compiling `engine.c` without affecting material in `engine.h` — so it has a direct effect on `engine.c` and no effect on `engine.h`.